# Ad Mob Rewarded Ad Verifier

Tags: admob

I am using Admob SDK for rewarded video ad in iOS application and set the ad unit and callback url in the google admob console for call back URL to my server through google admob server once user finish watching ad.

Is there additional coding that needs to be done in client application (iOS application) to make that callback url to hit my server from google admob server.

Could anyone please explain me the details. Please find the reference document below.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video-ssv

As per the document do I need to integrate Tink framework and user RewardAdVerifier class in iOS application to verify callback url.

Please let me know.